# Using a dev board as final commercial solution

Tags: embedded, board

I'm working on a small embedded project which controls electrical usage of a factory/department. My solution is limited regarding the production of the solution: I may sell 50 or 100 per year.

My question is: can I use a development board like Beaglebone or less AVR or Freescale to ship my solution to clients (with little enhancement: box it and label it... etc)?

Comment: Check [this](http://beagleboard.org/Community/Forums?place=topic%2Fbeagleboard%2FyeX5GkEbqZc%2Fdiscussion) out.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, yes.

A few development boards are sold below cost, as encouragement to try a new processor, and in these cases, the seller may impose limits such as 1 to 5 sales per customer. So beware of those : that would cause problems when you suddenly need 100. (This is probably a bigger problem with $1000 FPGA boards containing $2000 FPGAs...)

Arduinos definitely don't fall into that category, and I believe neither the Beaglebones nor the Raspberry Pi do. But if there's any doubt, talk with a sales rep from the company involved. And on the BeagleBone, see the link in Eugene's comment.

Another possible consideration is that using a standard board, unmodified, makes it a bit easier for someone else to copy your design and steal your market. If that's a consideration in your case, a custom board increases the barrier to doing so, but it can probably never be eliminated completely.

Eugene correctly points out that continuity of supply is a potential problem too : if possible, buy all you need plus a few spares when you move from prototype into production. With open-source boards like Arduinos and Beaglebones, archive the board design files : that way you can have more made by another supplier if the original supply dries up.

Comment: The main problem is undefined End-Of-Life for these products.

Comment: Very true, but usually the schematics, etc are all available for many dev boards, so one could roll-your-own at that stage.